# How to detach a noun modifier so it clearly stays a modifier?

Tags: grammar, nouns, ambiguity, modifiers

A noun modifier is a noun as an attribute of an other noun, like the “edge” in “edge case”. If the modifier is an adjective, it may be detached from a main noun. If the modifier is a noun, I think that separating it would make sense, but it could cause problems.

Consider these examples:

- “blue car” – “The car is blue.”
- “edge case” – “The case is edge.”
- “water slide” – “The slide is water.”

The first one is fine because “blue” is an adjective, so it is a modifier automatically. The second one is unusual but unambiguous because “edge” is a common countable noun, so it needs an article to be used as a standalone noun. But, still, I would rather avoid that. But the third is ambiguous because “water” can be a modifier and can be a standalone noun, so it is unclear what it means, if the slide is just related to water or it comprises water.

How can I detach the noun modifier so it would be clear that it is a modifier?

If I could transform every noun to an adjective meaning the same as the noun as a modifier, it would not be a problem because I could use the adjective. But that is often not possible. (The meaning of “edgy” is different from that of “edge” as a modifier.)

Comment: There are _adjectives_ that don't occur predicatively (nuclear reaction; former president; (heavy smoker); mere youth): some classifying, some privative, some applying to the class the referent is in (the class of youths). Premodifiers have many different semantic relations with the head nouns. Hyphens can be used to disambiguate where necessary (three-hundred-year-old trees / three hundred-year-old trees / three hundred year-old trees). But the actual semantic relation between premodifier and head noun must be learned for each specific case, and the structure used the way others normally do.

Comment: There is also the free association ... weak collocation ... strong collocation ... open compound continuum to bear in mind.

Comment: "The case is edge" does not sound idiomatic to me. "The case is an edge case" would be better.

Comment: I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding how attributive nouns work. In English we don't do what you're suggesting. It's like asking "instead of putting 'the' before a noun is there a way I can put 'the' after a noun?" Maybe this belongs on English Language Learners. Maybe you need to offer a specific case we can discuss, or to explain why you want to do this.

Comment: Noun1 + noun2 = *noun 2 that is contextually associated with noun1*: - -language department = the department contextually associated with language. - - walking stick - a stick that is contextually associated with walking -- beer bottle shape - a shape that is contextually associated with a bottle that is contextually associated with beer.

Comment: What @Greybeard said. An edge case is a case that is contextually associated with an edge (only applies with "extreme" parameters at the "edge" of the possible value range), and a water slide is a slide that is contextually associated with water (*lubricated* with running water, and/or deposits users into a water pool).

Comment: Adjectives and noun phrases can both be used as predicates, and often form compounds. But there are many different meanings available, normally pretty arbitrary, and many categories: _seeded lawn, seeded pepper, pony ride, snake bite, gala party/*party was gala, rice bags, Danish pastry, Danish accountant,_ etc. To answer your question - it varies. There isn't any single way.

Comment: How, here “edgy” is different from “edge”?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin “edge” as a modifier – related to an edge. “edgy” – [unusual in a way that is fashionable or exciting] or nervous ([source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/edgy)).

Comment: @StuartF I think that I understand how attributive nouns work in English. The question is because of my tendency to bend every natural language into something more systematic with high compositionality. That is that I try to decompose expressions into their basic parts and compose them according to some induced rules to express some uncommon things more efficiently or at all. I think that I will do what I described in the question naturally sometimes, but I would rather do it in a way which is easy to understand. That is why I asked the question.

Comment: @Greybeard Exactly, but I don't know what exactly “contextually” means there, so I ignore it. I understand noun modification as a general association. If I use a ‹noun 1› as a modifier, I mean something related to ‹noun 1›. So, if there would be nothing following the modifier ‹noun 1›, it would mean something unspecified related to ‹noun 1› in an unspecified way.

Comment: @matj1 Your daily usage might be limited to your definitions above, but do you really believe people working with multiple cases are restricted to black-and-white 'edge cases'. Don't you think when we see a set of N cases, several from two on in, and up to N-1 at the other extreme, can be 'edgy'… the more so since your last Comment seems to mean 'I like to make up my own rules…'?

Comment: @matj1 * So, if there would be nothing following the modifier ‹noun 1›, it would mean something unspecified related to ‹noun 1› in an unspecified way* No, It would be a noun, and often it would make no sense: "I hit him with a beer bottle." -> "I hit him with a beer." ??